# Rally excel plugin - export test cases for given story id

Tags: excel, plugins, rally

I am using the Rally excel plugin v2.4.4 and trying to export all TestCases for a given Story ID (`formattedId`). However, the filter query is not working. I have used the following queries -

- `WorkProduct.FormattedID = "S123456"`
- `Parent.FormattedID = "S123456"`

Is anyone aware of a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this following the [help](https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/grid-queries) topic. Used `WorkProduct.OID = "11222333"` to extract required test cases.